# sftp code required with out prompting for a password

Tags: unix, sftp

Working code for ftp is as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='host ip address'
USER='yourid'
PASSWD='yourpw'
FILE='output_file.csv'
ftp -n $HOST <<END
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put $FILE
quit
END
exit 0
```

This is a working ftp code for file transfer. What modification have to be done in this code to make it a Working SFTP code?

Comment: SFTP as in [secure ftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_file_transfer_program) or as in [simple ftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_File_Transfer_Protocol)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are mentioning `SFTP` [Secure FTP]. then you would require to generate the sftp keys (or the ssh keys) and exchange with the remote target server. They needs to be placed in the `.ssh` folder on remote machine. This would ensure *password-less* connectivity between the 2 hosts.

Then just issue the command

```
$ sftp remoteUser@host
```

You would get logged into the remote machine. You need to amend the code accordingly as you won't need the password now.